# Connecting a simple WebSocket (Java/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I'm trying to connect my javascript WebSocket to the backend.

I'm using this HTTP Hijack https://gist.github.com/missedone/76517e618486db746056

My Java code get's the response correctly `System.out.println(response);` (so there's connection) but this is not what I want.

I want to connect the backend (java) to the frontend (jquery/javascript) so I can send commands though the terminal instead of the current implementation

I'm only missing a way to connect this HttpHijack in the backend to my WebSocket in the front end.

Any help?

Java

```
 public String execConsole(String containerName) {
    Settings settings = Settings.getSettings();
    Container container = getContainer(containerName);

    //exec
    ExecCreateCmdResponse execCreateResp = dockerClient().execCreateCmd(container.getId()).withCmd("bash")
            .withAttachStderr(true).withAttachStdout(true).withAttachStdin(true).withTty(false).exec();

    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

    HttpHijack ws = null;
    try {
        ws = new HttpHijack(new URI("http://" + settings.getDockerIP() +":"+ settings.getDockerPort() +"/v1.19/exec/" + execCreateResp.getId() + "/start"));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String payload = "{\"Detach\": false,\"Tty\": false}";
    try {
        ws.post(headers, payload);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String request = "date > /tmp/nick2; cat /tmp/nick2; exit $?;";
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = ws.send(request);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InspectExecResponse execResp = dockerClient().inspectExecCmd(execCreateResp.getId()).exec();
    System.out.println("exec inspect: {}" + execResp);

    try {
        String response = IOUtils.readLines(input).toString();
        System.out.println(response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#btnConnect').click(function () { 
    $.ajax({
        url: '/connect-console',
        type: 'post',
        data: {containerName: containerName},
        success: function (url) {
            $('#connectDiv').hide();
            $('#terminalDiv').show();

            term = new Terminal({
                screenKeys: true,
                useStyle: true,
                cursorBlink: true
            });

            ws = new WebSocket(url,true);
            ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
            term.on('data', function (data) {
                ws.send(data);
            });
            term.open(document.getElementById("terminal"), true);
            ws.onopen = function() {
                console.log('ws connected');
            };
            ws.onerror = function() {
                console.log('ws error');
            };
            ws.onclose = function() {
                console.log('ws closed');
            };
            ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
                var decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
                var data = decoder.decode(evt.data);
                term.write(data);
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You're supposed to spend *a lot* of time researching this and trying to find a solution yourself. It sounds like you just dumped code here you found elsewhere and expect us to hand you the solution. That's not how this website works.

Comment: No. I've wasted many weeks to finally get this code.